Generalized Sampling pattern for regular polygons?
There is a sampling pattern used in FEM method for triangles, which can be seen here:

The rough description is that at each edge we have n samples (containing the endpoints) and then in the interior the number of samples remains roughly uniform.
The equivalent for the square is just a regular grid of points, like this one:

What I am looking for is, given a number $n$ and a regular polygon with $n$ sides, a rule such that:
Each side of the polygon has $n$ samples (including the endpoints), the interior is regularly sampled (i.e. the minimum distance between points is bounded).
I am not having much luck finding out how to do this.

If it is a regular polygon its barycentre $c$ can be found by calculating $$c = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n v_i.$$ Then you can construct $n$ triangles $c,v_i,v_{i+1}$ which can be regularly sampled like the triangles you showed.
